# Cron is unable to run my command, even though it works for me (inside docker container)

Tags: django, docker, cron

I have a Docker container for a project in Django (with a postgres db) and I created a small script in order to do an automatic backup every 24 hours.
In my cron file I have the following:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * whoami &>>/tmp/dbg.log
* * * * * cd /home/projects/my-project/ && . env/bin/activate && scripts/sh/auto_backup.sh &>>/tmp/cron_debug.log
```

**Edit**

The script that is running (auto_backup) looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")
./manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 > backups/backup_${today}.json && echo "Backup complete"
```

**Finished edit**

If I run the cron command myself, everything works just fine. But if I let cron do it, I always get the following error:

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket     "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am running this inside a Docker container, on my local machine everything runs smooth. The postgres database is indeed on another pod (in another container), but this doesn't seem to be a problem when I run the command manually. Also, I checked, and `whoami` always returns root, so it doesn't seem to be a problem of permissions.

Comment: Just curious, what is the dot `.` doing there in your cronjob?

Comment: It is the `source` command. It activates the virtualenv.

Comment: How do you connect to the database in the backup script?

Comment: I don't. I am using dumpdata from django, and the database connection is handled through the settings.

Comment: Something is wrong in the way you pass your database connection information, `Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket` means that you're falling back to the default of connecting to PostgreSQL locally, using a socket, but here you obviously want to connect over TCP.

Comment: Like I said before, I am not passing any information other than the project settings (which are correct)... I can tell what the error means, but given that I am activating the virtualenv before and that I am running a django command, I can not tell why it is trying to connect locally.

Comment: Just for clarity, I also added the content of my `auto_backup.sh` script.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Joren, no, not really. I ended up doing backups through Postgres directly. Sorry.